# Calculation about $dg \wedge \star df$.

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm trying to calculate about $dg \wedge \star df$.

By the definition of Hodge-star, I write
$$\star df=
\left(\partial_\mu f\right) g^{\mu \nu} \sqrt{|g|} \epsilon_{\nu \rho_1 \ldots \rho_{n-1}} d x^{\rho_1} \wedge \ldots \wedge d x^{\rho_{n-1}}
$$
and
$$dg=\partial_i g dx^i.$$
But I had problem calculating
$$(\partial_i g dx^i) \wedge \left(\partial_\mu f\right) g^{\mu \nu} \sqrt{|g|} \epsilon_{\nu \rho_1 \ldots \rho_{n-1}} d x^{\rho_1} \wedge \ldots \wedge d x^{\rho_{n-1}},$$
is there more direct way to calculate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By definition of the Hodge-$*$, $\alpha\wedge *\beta$ is just $g(\alpha,\beta)$ times the volume form holds for all pairs of $k$-forms, where $g$ is the induced metric. So in the case of one-forms, this is just the inverse metric, so in your situation, you simply get $$dg\wedge *df=\left(g^{\mu\nu}(\partial_\mu g)(\partial_\nu f)\right) \sqrt{|g|}dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge dx^n.$$
This follows quickly from your computation using that $dx^i\wedge dx^{\rho_1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx^{\rho_{n-1}}=\epsilon_{i\rho_1\dots\rho_{n-1}}dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge dx^n$.